# Using the AWS CLI tool for s3 sync -- how can I specify the storage tier?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm using the AWS CLI to use Amazon's S3 storage for backing up files:

`aws s3 sync /backup-these-files s3://my-backup`

How can I specify the `x-amz-storage-class` header, to tell it to put these files into the STANDARD-IA storage tier?

I can't figure the options with the AWS CLI to add a header or otherwise specify this option.

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-class-intro.html#sc-howtoset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `--storage-class STANDARD_IA` option.

> --storage-class (string) The type of storage to use for the object. Valid choices are: STANDARD | REDUCED_REDUNDANCY | STANDARD_IA | ONEZONE_IA | INTELLIGENT_TIERING | GLACIER | DEEP_ARCHIVE. Defaults to 'STANDARD'

**References**

[AWS S3 sync](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html)